# how to download csv file with login from https://online.aia.edu.au/ by python

Tags: python

I am trying download CSV file.
I need python code to download CSV.
Help me!
error:
PS C:\Users\Jacky\Documents\new_python_task\code> pip install PyQt4
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyQt4

Comment: Maybe a mod can bring this down? You are exposing your server....

Comment: which csv file?